# What is the algorithm to specify a fixed effects design matrix?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, experiment-design, fixed-effects-model, research-design

I have a procedure for generating the design matrix of an experiment that uses only fixed effect predictors.

The procedure depends on knowing the relationship between all pairs of predictors in the experiment: crossed or nested. Then, based on these pairwise crossed/nested relationships, the design matrix is constructed in a series of steps.

The procedure is described here:

---

***Step 1 - Intercept Column***

Create a single column that has N elements, where N is the total number of data points collected for the experiment, and write a 1 in every element.

***Step 2 - Simple Effects of Non-Nested Categorical Predictors***

A categorical unordered predictor that is not nested within any other predictors has (P-1) simple effect columns, where P is equal to the number of levels of the predictor. For each column, write 1's for the data points that are associated with the level that is associated with that column.

***Step 3 - Nested Simple Effects of Nested Categorical Predictors***

A categorical unordered predictor that is nested within one or more other predictors has (L * (Q-1)) nested simple effect columns, where L is the number of levels or level combinations of the nesting predictor or predictors, and Q is the number of nested levels per each nesting level/level combination.

***Step 4 - Simple Effects of Numerical Predictors***

Create a single column, and fill in the column elements with the numerical values of the predictor associated with the data points of the experiment.

***Step 5 - Two-Way Interactions***

For every pair of simple effect columns between different predictors, multiply them together.

***Step 6 - Three-way Interactions***

For every trio of simple effect columns between different predictors, multiply them together.

---

My question is: Does this procedure appear correct? Am I missing any important concepts for the construction of fixed effect design matrices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does appear correct, however it is only one of infinitely many possible approaches, as when you have a $n\times p$ design matrix $X$ then any $n\times p$ matrix $X'$ with the same image, i.e. the span(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_span) of its columns, would define the same model, with a different parameterization. The image of $X$ can be thought of as the set of all possible linear predictors you could fit.

The only really common deviation from what you describe would be using contrasts (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contrast_(statistics)) instead of the R-default of dummy-variables (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_variable_(statistics)).